# geting value of relative select element aftered with jquery

Tags: jquery, html

this is my html code:

```
<input type="button" class="addSection" value="Add section" />
<br />
<hr />
<div id='rep'></div>
```

and this is my script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.addSection').click(function() {

        $('#rep').after('<br />' +
            '<select class="srtCom">' +
            '<option value="key">key</option>' +
            '<option value="luck">luck</option>' +
            '<option value="college">college</option>' +
            '</select>' +
            '<br />');


        alert($('#rep').next('.srtCom').val());
        });
     });
```

my question is why i cant get value of aftered select element.
i used next() function to reach select element and get its value but in alert() function i get undefined!!
thanks for your help.

Comment: the next element here is `br`. not your `<select>` having class of `.srtCom`. You should use `.nextUntil('.srtCom').next()`.

Comment: @KingKing *"the next element here is br"* - No it's not, it's `$('#rep').next`.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek check it yourself https://jsfiddle.net/ruftftdx/

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek the `.next('.srtCom')` checks the result if it has class `.srtCom` before returning the element but because `<br>` does not have such class, it will result in `undefined`.

Comment: i add **'.srtCom'** to next function to find this class . why you next element is **br**

Comment: @KingKing My bad I didn't notice the `<br />` inside the `after` method. I thought you where mistaking it as the `input` element as `#rep`.

Comment: @ King King how can i fix them???

Comment: @Black_Hammer you don't understand how the `.next` works. You might think that it should find the ***first*** next sibling element having class of `.srtCom`. But that's not how it works. The next element should be always the next adjacent one, the inside string is just used for filtering/checking if it meets the criteria. In your case you have a `<br>` inserted after your `#rep`. Don't you see that?

Comment: @Black_Hammer the answer is already in my first comment (you did not read it carefully, did you?) https://jsfiddle.net/ruftftdx/1/

Comment: @King King i underestand thanks for your help.    :)

Answer (score 0):

I know this isn't what you specifically asked, but pedantry forces me to rewrite the "logic" behind your jQuery code here.

Instead of appending an element as pure HTML, append it as a jQuery object:

```
var srtCom = $('<select class="srtCom">').css({
  "display": "block",
  "margin": "1em 0"
}); // instead of using <br /> tags, use margin instead - allows for cleaner code
var options = ['key', 'luck', 'college']; // probably best to do it this way for future compatibility
for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
  srtCom.append('<option value="' + options[i] + '">' + options[i] + '</option>');
}
srtCom.insertAfter($("#rep"));
alert(srtCom.find("option:selected").val());
```

Here's a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x1bofp07/) to show you what it looks like.

The benefit of such an approach is the increased modularity - as the `srtCom` variable now contains a direct reference to the `<select>` tag's respective jQuery object, you can do a lot more stuff with it now, as opposed to trying to select it based on its relative location to `<div id="rep"></div>`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use **nextAll()** to find the select element like below

```
$('#rep').nextAll().closest('.srtCom')
```

**Snippet**

```js
   

 $(document).ready(function() {
  $('.addSection').click(function() {
    $('#rep').after('<br />' +
                    '<select class="srtCom">' +
                    '<option value="key">key</option>' +
                    '<option value="luck">luck</option>' +
                    '<option value="college">college</option>' +
                    '</select>' +
                    '<br />');
    alert($('#rep').nextAll().closest('.srtCom').val());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" class="addSection" value="Add section" />
<br />
<hr />
<div id='rep'></div>
```

Here is the working jsfiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/jxhukwqw/1/

Comment: $('#rep').nextAll('.srtCom').val()    ... https://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/ruftftdx/3/

Comment: more comfortable code `alert($('#rep').next().next().val());`

Comment: @Black_Hammer I updated my jsfiddle as $('#rep').nextAll().closest('.srtCom').val().I think it is the safest way;)